# AWS-Amplify Tutorial Not getting Past Step 1

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am following a tutorial with the intention on getting my Android App to connect to an AWS DynamoDB.. I have followed this tutorial to the T, but I can't even get past Step 1!

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start

**Prerequisites**

- Node (I have)
- Android Studio version 3.1 or higher (I am using 3.6)
- Android SDK with a minimum API level of 15 (I have 29)

However, when I go to Run 'Make Project', it tells me that I am missing **amplify-gradle-config.json**

Which, I am. Nothing told me to generate it. I don't see how to generate it.

Comment: Given that `amplify-gradle-config.json` is called out in "Step 3" you might just want to run through all of the steps and ignore errors which are explained in later instructions. But yeah instructions should call out when errors are generated prematurely.

Comment: A reasonable assessment. However, the next steps require components that are created from the 'Make Project'.

Comment: Don't know if you have those two additional gradle tasks `modelgen` and `amplifyPush` setup in your project. Just for reference here is a older Amplify project from an AWS workshop I attended: https://github.com/kkemple/aws-amplify-android-workshop